# Why does Jackson ObjectReader `with` function not work with Scala?

Tags: scala, jackson

I am currently reading through the linked [docs](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/reading-csv-with-jackson-c4e74a15ddc1) and I have the following...

```
val builder = CsvSchema.builder()
splitString.foreach(col=>builder.addColumn(col));
header = builder.build()
val it: MappingIterator[util.Map[String, String]] =
        mapper.readerForListOf(classOf[String])
              .with(header)
              .readValue(line);
```

This seems to match the demo code but when I try running I get...

> Service.scala:<1369..1373>: an identifier expected, but 'with' found

I also don't see with as an option in the autocomplete. What do I need?

Comment: Rather use a Scala lib

Comment: What is a good lib that handles csv and other serialized formats as well as Jackson and also supports Scala 3?

Comment: There is a lot lib, but anyway using Jackson as-is doesn't benefit in any way of Scala

Comment: I am not using Scala because of Jackson, I am using Jackson because I can't find a good scala alternative. Most that I find only work with 2.13

Comment: Because you have searched rather ... There are plenty of json Scala lib (Circe, lift, play, ...)

Answer (score 2):

Seem to have gotten it with...

```
val it: MappingIterator[util.Map[String, String]] =
        mapper.readerForListOf(classOf[String])
              .`with`(header)
              .readValue(line);
```

Answer (score 2):

`with` is a *reserved word* in Scala. Reserved words are not legal identifiers, see [Section 1.1 *Identifiers*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers) of the [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/) [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> The following names are reserved words **instead of being members of the syntactic class *id* of lexical identifiers**.

Identifiers can also be formed by [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> Finally, an identifier may also be formed by an **arbitrary string between back-quotes** (host systems may impose some restrictions on which strings are legal for identifiers). The identifier then is composed of all characters excluding the backquotes themselves.

Note the phrase "arbitrary string" without any restriction. This means, it can be a reserved word as well.

The *exact problem* you are having is actually explicitly addressed:

> When one needs to access Java identifiers that are reserved words in Scala, use backquote-enclosed strings. For instance, the statement `Thread.yield()` is illegal, since `yield` is a reserved word in Scala. However, here's a work-around: `` Thread.`yield`() ``

As a sidenote: you should try using a different IDE or editor. Even the extremely simplistic, crappy syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow clearly shows the problem right there in your question: `with` is highlighted as a reserved word, the same way as `val`. A good IDE or editor should do the same and immediately show you that `with` is a reserved word and not a legal identifier.

Comment: Is anyone else bothered by the fact that the SLS uses two different spellings of "back-quotes" in two consecutive sentences? :-D